# python float to string in exponent without dot

Tags: python

Basically, given a float point number, say

```
f=0.25
```

I want

```
'25e-02'
```

I would only consider numbers with two decimals. **How can I do this without multiplying 100??**

If I simply do `'%.1e'%0.25`, I get `'2.5e-01'`, which is not what I want. **I wonder if there is any way that I can choose the number in the exponent part, namely the `xx` in `e-xx`**.

Comment: The answer is no, Python doesn't provide you a way to do that directly.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Okay, thanks. Then I guess I need to make my own function to make it...